# Is it possible to modify compiler include path for Dymola?

Tags: c, external, modelica, dymola

This question is raised due to a situation that I encountered

Say I have these external files and some declarations or definitions in them:

1. foo1.h

   > `extern void ext_func();`
2. foo1.c

   > void ext_func(){
   >                .... 
   >           }
3. foo2.c

   ```
       #include "foo1.h"
   ```

   > ```
   >    int Modelica_func(){
   >       ext_func(); 
   >      }
   > ```

I defined **ext_func()** in foo1.c. Then, in foo1.h I declared it to be **extern**, because I want to use it in foo2.c. **Modelica_func()** is the function that I will be using in Modelica.

The compiler always throws out **error LNK2019** to me complaining **unresolved external symbol**, I guess it's probably due to the reason that the header file cannot find it's matching c file. I am working in Dymola, and I've put all of these files in **WorkingFolder/Sources/Include**. But still I got the same error. I want others to see my code, so I cannot use static or dynamic library.

Greatly appreciated if anyone could help me a bit of this. THANKS!

Comment: Are you building foo1.c? Are you linking it into the binary? At this point the headers don't matter, everything is already compiled.

Answer (score 1):

You can find some details in Section 12.9.4 of the [Modelica Specification](https://www.modelica.org/documents/ModelicaSpec33.pdf).